# content loaded with ajax not applying css properly

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a project in which a navigation menu is supposed to open another menu and I want that second menu to be loaded with Ajax. The problem I am getting is that once the menu is loaded with Ajax, the css is not properly applied. In order to make this very obvious I have duplicated the exact same code for the menu, I have put once the code in the main file and the same code in the file that is loaded so that you can see the menu move, and also loose its :hover rule. Here is a gif:

[image]

As you can see, the menu moves and the different styles for hover are not applied.

Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

  </head>

  <body>


      <?php include('main.php'); ?>




    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/noIntro.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/general.js"></script>

  </body>
```

main.php

```
<?php include 'db_connect.php'; ?>
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<div id="subheader" class="notVisible">

  <nav id="menu2">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="request4guitars.php" class="firstlevel">ACOUSTIQUES</a><span class="dot">•</span>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#.html" class="firstlevel">ARCHTOPS</a><span class="dot">•</span></li>
       <li><a href="#.html" class="firstlevel">SIGNATURES</a><span class="dot">•</span></li>
       <li><a href="#.html" class="firstlevel">COLLECTIONS</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>

</div>

<ul id="guitarWindow">

  <?php



    $inner = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM models WHERE cat_id = 1");

    while ($i = mysqli_fetch_array($inner)) {

      if ($i['id'] == 1){

      echo '<li><a href="#" class="selected">'.$i['name'].'<span>'.$i['cases'].' cases</span></a></li>';}

      else {

      echo '<li><a href="#">'.$i['name'].'<span>'.$i['cases'].' cases</span></a></li>';}

    }
   ?>
</ul>
```

The php tag inside the "guitarWindow" ul is what loads the first menu.

Here is the ajax content that is loaded, which is the same code:

request4guitars.php

```
<ul id="guitarWindow">
  <?php include 'db_connect.php'; ?>
  <?php



    $inner = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM models WHERE cat_id = 1");

    while ($i = mysqli_fetch_array($inner)) {

      if ($i['id'] == 1){

      echo '<li><a href="#" class="selected">'.$i['name'].'<span>'.$i['cases'].' cases</span></a></li>';}

      else {

      echo '<li><a href="#">'.$i['name'].'<span>'.$i['cases'].' cases</span></a></li>';}

    }
   ?>

</ul>
```

And finally the js that uses ajax to load the content:

```
$( document ).on('click', 'nav#menu2 a', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var url = this.href;
    $( "nav#menu2 a.currentSubheader" ).removeClass("currentSubheader");
    $(this).addClass("currentSubheader");
      $( '#guitarWindow').load('../request4guitars.php' + ' #guitarWindow', function(){

    });

});
```

I am not including the css as the css works to begin with. I am still just learning php and ajax so this may be a very simple mistake. Thank you.

EDIT----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

After a bit of investigation, the lack of hover styles has to do with another element that is invisible and on top of the second menu. So the only issue here is that the menu changes position after loaded with ajax.

Comment: From the gif it looks like you need to click first before you get a hover.

Comment: the first click is required to screen record in order to make the gif, nothing to do with the code